# Modify IMAP and SMTP servers to not use default for Gmail

Tags: smtp, gmail, imap

I'm using google apps for my email. Configured it like this:

```
Incoming Mail (IMAP) Server - requires SSL: imap.gmail.com 
Use SSL: Yes
Port: 993 
Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server - requires TLS: smtp.gmail.com 
Use Authentication: Yes 
Use STARTTLS: Yes (some clients call this SSL)
Port: 465 or 587
```

But how do I use other named servers, where you don't see gmail.com? Like imap.mydomain.com instead of imap.gmail.com. same for the outgoing server. 
is it possible with changes to my DNS settings?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Mask that you use Google's ssrvers? Cannot be if they send your mail, so you'll have to set up your own mail server. Anything else (dns CNAME aliases for the servers etc.): why?

Comment: Yes, mask it. For some reasons. But doesn't work with CNAMES as aliasses I figured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do it, you can setup some CNAMEs in your DNS zone:

```
imap.example.com. IN CNAME imap.gmail.com.
smtp.example.com. IN CNAME smtp.gmail.com.
```

It would still be pretty easy for someone to figure out you're using Google Apps, though this will hide it from and end-user who does not care to look this up.

Comment: Hi, doesn't work. DNS is updated (Google DNS, so good speed for changes). 
So, it's changed, but doesn't work when I use the settings in Outlook..

Other idea's?

Comment: "Can't connect to mailserver. Mailserver unavailable." I know why, because the CNAME's aren't recognized.
So I think it isn't possible to use CNAME's to solve my "problem" of using my own names instead of *.gmail.com..

Comment: Yes, they are: `imap.gmail.com` is a CNAME for `gmail-imap.l.google.com` in itself. Did you notice each all 4 hostnames have a trailing `.`? That is critical to it functioning correctly. Without them, it becomes `imap.example.com.example.com. IN CNAME imap.gmail.com.example.com.`.

Comment: Hmm, still the same error. Did change the CNAME records to gmail-imap.l.google.com. and gmail-smtp.l.google.com.

Comment: I've just setup a CNAME and it works fine. You're going to have to give us your domain name.